# insert the data of text inputs to json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

guys i know it is dummy question but i want to insert the data of input texts of the added row into json array .. whenever i tried to output the `val` it gives me undefined .. here is my code

```
function insertRow(){
var i=1;
  for (var propertyNames in grid.data[0]) {
      var val = document.getElementsByName("input"+i).value;
      grid.data.push({propertyNames:val});
      i++;
  }
   }

  function addRow() {
  var i = 1;
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var cell = row.insertCell();
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.type = "checkbox";
  element.name = "chk";
  cell.appendChild(element);

  for (var propertyNames in grid.data[0]) {
    cell = row.insertCell(i);

    element = document.createElement("input");
    element.type = "text";
    element.size = 10;
    element.name = "input" + i;
    cell.appendChild(element);
    i++;
  }
}
```

my HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="Add row" class="btn" id="previous" onclick="addRow();"></input>
    <input type="button" value="Insert" class="btn" id="insert" onclick="insertRow();"></input>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i did .. please have a look

Comment: you don't have a name attribute in your html code. check my answer for further details

Answer (score 0):

A lot of mistakes...

> 1. `var table = document.getElementById("table");`. You don't have element with `id = table`
> 2. In `grid.data[0]` grid is `null`
> 3. `<input />`?
> 4. `Developer console` in any browser - it's very useful tool